# lando - mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, drupal-8, lando

I am trying to exporting database via lando command which is documented on 
https://docs.lando.dev/config/drupal8.html#connecting-to-your-database

```
lando db-export database_backup.sql
```

mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (111) when trying to connect
    Failed to create file: /app/database_backup.sql

Here is `lando info`

```
service: 'database',
    urls: [],
    type: 'mysql',
    internal_connection: {
      host: 'database',
      port: '3306'
    },
    external_connection: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '32807'
    },
    creds: {
      database: 'drupal8',
      password: 'drupal8',
      user: 'drupal8'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted here fixed it for me: https://github.com/lando/acquia/issues/27

I just added all the DB credentials to the `.lando.yml` at it worked again.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your MySQL server does not work properly.

`lando rebuild`

should fix it.